# How to Arrange a column of a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with values

```
Product     Range    Sold
  A          1-3      5
  A          4-7      23
  A          8-15     2
  B          4-7      4
  B          8-15     1
```

I need the output as

```
                      Sold
Product     Range    
  A          1-3      5
             4-7      23
             8-15     2
  B          4-7      4
             8-15     1
```

Can this be done by any built-in functions or any pivot table functions?

Comment: Is first level `sorted` ?

Comment: Is possible first level is `[A, A, A, B, B, A, A] ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need `MultiIndex` use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Product','Range'])
```

If not and first level is sorted, use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['Product'] = df['Product'].mask(df['Product'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
  Product Range  Sold
0       A   1-3     5
1           4-7    23
2          8-15     2
3       B   4-7     4
4          8-15     1
```

Comment: For your second option, if the input is [A, A, A, B, B, A, A], should the output be [A, . . B . A .] or [A . . B . . .]?

Comment: @coldspeed - It is possible, but with all previous answer s seems `df.set_index(['Product','Range'])` is what OP need.

Comment: Oh great, the user has accepted this answer meaning it was a dupe. I don't know what to think. I am deleting my answer, because this is a rubbish question.

Comment: sry mate   was kinda busy the first level is sorted