# how to synchronize data frames in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have two data frames

```
  0 Product     Range(Days)    Sold
  1   A          1-3            5
  2              4-7            23
  3              8-15           2
  4   B          4-7            4
  5              8-15           1
  6   C          1-3            5
  7   D          1-3            2
  8   E          1-3            9
```

and

```
0 Product     Repair_Calls
1    A            2 
2    C            45
3    D            32
4    E            1
```

Can it be merged into one with repair calls being placed equally with respect to the product and not by 0-4

```
  0 Product     Range(Days)    Sold     Repair_Calls
  1   A          1-3            5           2
  2              4-7            23
  3              8-15           2
  4   B          4-7            4           0
  5              8-15           1
  6   C          1-3            5           45
  7   D          1-3            2           32
  8   E          1-3            9            1
```

Comment: Can you please stop misleading users with problematic input? Those first two columns are Multiindexes right? The fact that you accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50674086/4909087) shows that you are incapable of properly describing your question, so only people with outside context are actually capable of understanding what you want. I would also recommend you didn't keep creating new accounts for the purpose of asking questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Arrange a column of a Dataframe in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674086/how-to-arrange-a-column-of-a-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: @coldspeed me having doubt so referenced that one but mine had diffrent criteria so copied that  one for asking this is my first qn

Answer (score 1):

```
df3 = df1.join(df2,on='Product')
```

[Reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)